# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater; android studio

Tags: java, android, android-automotive, android-asynclayoutinflater

This error is thrown when I try to run my automotive application in android studio.

It also gives the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"androidx.asynclayoutinflater.view.AsyncLayoutInflater" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mycarapplication-lVN5UU1ZLpkjCRu9JNCF9w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mycarapplication-lVN5UU1ZLpkjCRu9JNCF9w==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
```

How can I solve this error?

My build.gradle file (app level) is:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mycarapplication"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
    
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.3.0'
    //implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

My build.gradle file (project level) is:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}
    
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my gradle.properties is:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

Comment: Sounds like you have an unresolved dependency. Can you upload your `build.gradle` file? These types of errors are impossible to fix without more context.

Comment: updated my question with build.gradle  files @theChoosyBeggar

Answer (score 0):

implementation "androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0"

You should add this dependency.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).